# Router speed not matching my ISP speed

Tags: networking, router, speed, bandwidth, isp

My ISP recently upgraded me to 150 mbps, I can only get close to this if I wire directly from the modem to my computer. If I wire through my router it maxes at 55, the router model is Linksys E1550, it says it is suppose to support 150 mbps are there settings I should change?

Comment: What are you using, WiFi 802.11a, b, g, ...?

Comment: OP says he's using "wire"

Comment: @Jim The WAN/LAN ports on that router are 100Mbit.

Answer (score 6):

This is a 'semi-usual' result in that many(most?) routers cannot handle much speed going through their WAN interface. They can do fine when transferring data between LAN ports, but when it comes to WAN, their performance can be very sub-par. Up until relatively recently this wasn't that big of a deal since residential internet connection was in 5-20mbit range. But now that ISPs finally started to increase speeds people started noticing that their routers can't get above 50-60mbit.

What can be done about it, from easiest to hardest:

1. Make sure that connection between your router and your modem is gigabit and not 100mbit(half-duplex).
2. Try to turn off some of your router's (fancy/unnecessary) features, such as QoS or DoS protection or something else it might have that could affect router's cpu/network load.
3. Make sure your router is running the best available Linksys firmware. (Recently there was some commotion regarding Linksys router "cloud" features. I don't know if it affects your model, but perhaps consider avoiding that).
4. If these things still don't help, if available, consider looking into flashing your router with an alternative firmware/os. The most popular one is DD-WRT, but there is a huge number of other firmwares. Some of them are created with specific purpose in mind, such as highest performance or more features or something else. Some alternative firmware packages produce much better transfer speeds and go beyond the limits of stock version.
5. If that still doesn't help you, it's time to buy a better router. Do proper research to make sure that the model you'll buy truly supports 100mbit+ transfer speeds and not just a 'gigabit' branding.

Comment: Even putting a consumer grade switch between even a 12 mbit/sec cable modem and a properly configured 100 baseTX PC would drop throughput by approximately half... or greater (circa 2004).  I advise that before time, money and effort are spent on reconfiguring a router, that you test your throughput while connected to a separate switch between your modem and your system.  If the throughput still suffers similarly with only a switch in place, then  you might want to hold off on router work.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be very quick to blame the router. To be more informed about how your ISP's speed works I'd read [this article](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_be_sure_im_getting_the_internet_speed_im_paying_for.html). I can tell you right now however the speeds they say you'll get almost NEVER match up to what you actually get.

Comment: OP says he can get close to the advertised speed when he connects his computer directly to the modem bypassing the router. does not sound like ISP's problem.

Comment: @AlexP. Good thing the article doesn't only cover ISP's.

Comment: there is nothing relevant in that article.

Comment: Then thy should of read the "Your Network Can Affect Your Results". Or the "Your Home Might Affect Your Results" sections before thy speaks.